# bindable flexlayout in MAUI: all items are wrapped in the same layout; not each item

Tags: xamarin, maui

I am trying to display something similar to this:

[image]

I cannot use listview, nor collectionview, because all of this is already a child of a scrollview, and then the layouts just generate MASSIVE whitespace, as they cant measure their height properly.

I stumbled upon bindable flexlayout. So I set this up:

```
 <FlexLayout 
             Wrap="Wrap" JustifyContent="Start" Direction="Row" AlignItems="Start" AlignContent="Start"
       BindableLayout.ItemsSource="{Binding Sample}" 
       BindableLayout.ItemTemplate="{StaticResource AndroidItemTemplate}">
   </FlexLayout>


<ContentPage.Resources>
       <DataTemplate x:Key="AndroidItemTemplate">
           <ContentView Margin="3" BackgroundColor="White">
                 <Frame CornerRadius="20" HeightRequest="40" Padding="10" BackgroundColor="{StaticResource LiteGreen}">
                     <Label FontFamily="MyriadExtraBold" FontSize="14" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding .}"/>
                 </Frame>                
            </ContentView>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ContentPage.Resources>
```

But the result is this:

[image]

While the items are in fact where they belong, instead of giving each item the blue frame, ALL of them are in the same frame.

What is going on here?

Thank you

Comment: Add to question the code that declares `Sample`. Something like `public ObservableCollection<string> Sample { get; set; }`? (or `... List<string> ...`).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code, I did a test , but I couldn't reproduce this problem.I just replaced the bind property `.` with my item's property `Name`.

```
<Label  Text="{Binding Name}"/>
```

The value of the property you bind should be very long.

```
<Label FontFamily="MyriadExtraBold" FontSize="14" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" Text="{Binding .}"/>
```

The result on my side is:

[image]

Comment: To make it clear what you did differently than the question, please show your `ItemsSource=...`, and show the declaration of the property used by ItemsSource.

Comment: I'm not sure if this answer really qualifies as an answer since it doesn't actually solve the OP's problem in its current state.